# Constant Lag in CDC Pipeline (JDBC Sink Connector)

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am running a CDC Pipeline (data streaming) with source DB as PostgreSQL (**Debezium Source Connector**) and target DB also PostgreSQL with **confluent JDBC Sink Connector (10.6.4)** reading data from Kafka. I am experiencing a constant lag around 40 messages. And publishing rate is 5 messages per second.
I also a another **JDBC Sink Connector** running to a different PostgreSQL DB but lag is around 10 messages.

Even though i tried to modify the following properties still lag didn't reduced:

```
max.poll.records=5000
max.poll.interval.ms=300000 
fetch.min.bytes=100000
fetch.max.wait.ms=500
fetch.min.bytes=100000
consumer.override.auto.commit.interval.ms=100
consumer.override.offset.flush.interval.ms=200
batch.size=4000
```

How do i reduce the lag, so that pipeline works in real time or near real time?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely because the JDBC sink connector does not actively perform any batch operations when the connector receives a collection of `SinkRecord` to be processed.

This is an enhancement that is actively being worked on and we plan to introduce batch support in Debezium 2.5.0.Final, due out in December.

If you want to track the progress of this work, please see [DBZ-6317](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DBZ-6317)

Comment: Does Confluent JDBC Sink (Version 10.6.4)  Connector also doesn't support batch operation?
I am using Confluent JDBC Sink Connector and at Source PG Debezium Sink Connector is being used.

Comment: It should, but you'd need to check the documentation to be sure.